# cURL not sending file attachments on Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, curl

I know this has been covered a lot on stackoverflow but I can't seem to find a solution to my particular issue.

We have a WP based site hosted in Azure so have needed to write our own plugin to handle email from the site using Azure Communication Services via cURL to post to the REST API.

The original script for this was written by a colleague but i'm now trying to get this to allow users to upload file attachments.

I've got so far but now i'm stuck. The emails are sending but nothing is attached.

Can anyone help?

This is our code

```
<?php
class ACSMailer{

    public static function SendMail($atts){

        $to = $atts['to'];
        $subject = $atts['subject'];
        $message = $atts['message'];
        $headers = $atts['headers'];

        $attachments = [];

        $atch = $atts['attachments'];

        foreach($atch as $atchkey => $atchval) {

            $attachments[] = [
                'name' => basename($atchval),
                'contentType' => mime_content_type($atchval),
                'contentInBase64' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($atchval)),
            ];
        }

        //error_log('HEADERS: '. print_r($atts, true));
        // TODO: Check for HTML and send as plain text

        $settings = get_option('acs_settings_option_name');
        $endpoint = $settings["endpoint"];
        $key = base64_decode($settings["key"]);

        $bodyArray = array(
            'sender' => 'donotreply@cardiffcouncildev.co.uk',
            'content' => array('subject' => $subject, 'html' => $message),
            'importance' => 'normal',
            'recipients' => array('to' => array(array('email' => $to))),
            'attachment' => $attachments,
            'disableUserEngagementTracking' => true
            );
        $bodyStr = json_encode($bodyArray);
        $hashedBodyStr = base64_encode(hash('sha256', $bodyStr, true));

        $dateStr = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T');

        $fullEndpoint = $endpoint . '/emails:send?api-version=2021-10-01-preview';
        $hostStr = str_replace('https://', '', $endpoint);
        $url = str_replace($endpoint, '', $fullEndpoint);
        
        $stringToSign = 'POST' . "\n" . $url . "\n" . $dateStr . ';' . $hostStr . ';' . $hashedBodyStr;
        $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToSign, $key, true));
        $uuid = vsprintf( '%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex(random_bytes(16)), 4) );


        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $fullEndpoint,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $bodyStr,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Date: ' . $dateStr,
                'Authorization: HMAC-SHA256 SignedHeaders=date;host;x-ms-content-sha256&Signature=' . $signature,
                'x-ms-content-sha256: ' . $hashedBodyStr,
                'repeatability-request-id: ' . $uuid,
                'repeatability-first-sent: ' . $dateStr
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        
        error_log('DATE: '. $dateStr);
        error_log('$endpoint: ' . $endpoint);
        error_log('$fullEndpoint: ' . $fullEndpoint);
        error_log('$key: ' . $key);
        error_log('$bodyStr: ' . $bodyStr);
        error_log('$dateStr: ' . $dateStr);
        error_log('$url: ' . $url);
        error_log('$stringToSign : ' . $stringToSign );
        error_log('$signature: ' . $signature);
        error_log('$uuid: ' . $uuid);
        error_log('$hashedBodyStr: ' . $hashedBodyStr);
        error_log('$bodyArray: ' . print_r($bodyArray, true));
        error_log('API RESPONSE: ' . $response);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to get it working with the following code. Basically i played around with the loop that creates the array of attached files. Plus turned out the endpoint was wrong.

```
public static function SendMail($atts){

    $to = $atts['to'];
    $subject = $atts['subject'];
    $message = $atts['message'];
    $headers = $atts['headers'];

    $atch = $atts['attachments'];
    //error_log('$atch: '. print_r($atch, true));

    foreach($atch as $atchkey => $atchval) {

        $attachments[] = array(
            'name' => basename($atchval),
            'contentType' => mime_content_type($atchval),
            'contentInBase64' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($atchval)),
        );
    }

    //error_log('HEADERS: '. print_r($atts, true));
    // TODO: Check for HTML and send as plain text

    $settings = get_option('acs_settings_option_name');
    $endpoint = $settings["endpoint"];
    $key = base64_decode($settings["key"]);

    $bodyArray = array(
        'senderAddress' => 'donotreply@cardiffcouncildev.co.uk',
        'content' => array('subject' => $subject, 'html' => $message),
        'importance' => 'normal',
        'recipients' => array('to' => array(array('address' => $to))),
        'attachments' => $attachments,
        'disableUserEngagementTracking' => true
        );
    $bodyStr = json_encode($bodyArray);
    $hashedBodyStr = base64_encode(hash('sha256', $bodyStr, true));

    $dateStr = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T');

    $fullEndpoint = $endpoint . '/emails:send?api-version=2023-03-31';
    $hostStr = str_replace('https://', '', $endpoint);
    $url = str_replace($endpoint, '', $fullEndpoint);
    
    $stringToSign = 'POST' . "\n" . $url . "\n" . $dateStr . ';' . $hostStr . ';' . $hashedBodyStr;
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToSign, $key, true));
    $uuid = vsprintf( '%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex(random_bytes(16)), 4) );


    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $fullEndpoint,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $bodyStr,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Date: ' . $dateStr,
            'Authorization: HMAC-SHA256 SignedHeaders=date;host;x-ms-content-sha256&Signature=' . $signature,
            'x-ms-content-sha256: ' . $hashedBodyStr,
            'repeatability-request-id: ' . $uuid,
            'repeatability-first-sent: ' . $dateStr
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    
}
```

But it's only sending image files. docs, pdf's or zip files aren't being sent.

Comment: In you original code you had: `error_log('API RESPONSE: ' . $response);` it might help to know what  is in `$response` when you says something is not being send.

Comment: that's the thing - there was no response. It's almost like it just doesn't run when the files are anything but image files